# Accessing Custom Filebeat tags on Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder, filebeat

I am new to filebeat and logstash. Would like to know how access custom field, inserted using filebeat on logstash end.

Example filebeat:

```css
filebeat:
  # List of prospectors to fetch data.
  prospectors:
      paths:
        - /root/logstash/log/*.log
      input_type: log
      fields:
        samplevar: 1004
  logstash:
  hosts: ["172.31.1.162:5044"]
```

Now how do i access samplevar on logstash end?

Logstash configuration

```html
output{

 stdout{
   codec =>  line { format => "{\"Date\": \"%{date}\", \"PID\": \"%{PID}\", \"Description\": \"%{description}\", \"%{[fields][samplevar]}\"}"}
 }
}
```

But samplevar is not returning any value

Comment: try just using `stdout { codec => rubydebug }` this will show you the entire event and you'll be able to see if samplevar is stored somewhere

Answer (score 0):

According to 
[the filebeat docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#configuration-fields)
custom fields added will be subfields of the `fields` field.

To access this in Logstash you would use `%{[fields][samplevar]}`.

To store Filebeat added fields in the root, allowing Logstash to access them like `%{samplevar}` use the [filebeat setting `fields_under_root: true`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#fields-under-root)

Comment: Hi Will, Thanks for the reply, i tried your suggestion, logstash throws exception for the configuration

Comment: have you run --config-test

Comment: yes i did 
    beats {
  port => 5044
  type => meter
  samplevar => ${[fields][portvariable]}
 }
The given configuration is invalid. Reason: Expected one of #, ", ', -, [, { at line 12, column 16 (byte 228) after input {
line 12 is samplevar.

Comment: please edit your question and add how you are trying to access this variable

Comment: Hi Will, i updated the post added output part of logstash where i access the samplevar from filebeat